# PHP & Wordpress: print array content

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm to dumb right now …

```
print_r($terms);
```

does this …

```
Array
(
    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 7
            [name] => Testwhatever
            [slug] => testwhatever
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 7
            [taxonomy] => event_type
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 2
            [object_id] => 8
        )

)
```

How can I `print` the slug?
I thought print `print($terms->slug)` should do the job, but it says: "Trying to get property of non-object"

**update:**

```
function get_event_term($post) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $post->ID, 'event_type' );
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
        print_r($terms);
        return $terms[7]->slug;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an array of objects (even if it contains only a single entry at index "7"), not a single object

```
echo $terms[7]->slug;
```

With multiple "things

```
foreach ($terms as $term) echo $term->slug;
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question. The problem is that this "7" is a dynamic number specifically for each post in wordpress. I have no idea what number it is. It doesn't seem to be the `post->ID`

Comment: @matt Array `$terms` always has one element, or it could have more?

Comment: it could have more I guess. Normally it's set to one, but it is possible to add multiple terms to a post.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
print_r($terms[7]->slug);
```

you object stdclass is in array[7] offset.

Answer (score 2):

Or, to complicate things a little bit:

```
array_walk($terms, function($val,$key) use(&$terms){ 
    var_dump($val->slug);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
print ($terms[7]->slug);
```

Answer (score 0):

`print_r ($terms[7]->slug)` looks logical to me, since it's an array of objects

**UPDATE**

Since you are unsure how many items `get_event_term` should return, you should return an Array.

```
function get_event_term($post) {
    $aReturn = array();
    $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $post->ID, 'event_type' );
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
        print_r($terms);
        foreach($terms as $term){ // iterate through array of objects
            $aReturn[] = $term->slug; // get the property that you need
        }
    }
    return $aReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function using the **wp_parse_args** system to manage its single **$args** argument, which could be given whatever values you wanted. In this case $args stores detailed display overrides, a pattern found in many WordPress functions.

```
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $term->name );
echo $arg[157]['term_id']; //output 157
echo $arg[157]['name'];  //output Entertainment
```

works fine for me more detail

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args